# Serialize List<BufferedImage> in a file that contains all of my objects

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, awt

I'm trying to serialize List of BufferedImage
case reading:-

```
List <BufferedImage> = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        public void serialize()
    {
       getDraftApp().getSerializeImages().add(ImageIO.read(new 
       ByteArrayInputStream(read(image))));
try {
            String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")+"Applications"+"\\"+getsHandler().getDraftApp().getAppId()+"-"+getsHandler().getDraftApp().getAppVersion()+"\\"+"app.proj";
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            System.out.println("Data is saved in : "+getsHandler().getDraftApp().getPath());
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(getsHandler().getDraftApp());
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved!");
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(ObjectManagements.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
        }
            public byte[] read(File file) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
            InputStream ios = null;
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ios = new FileInputStream(file);
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }finally {
                try {
                    if (ous != null)
                        ous.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                try {
                    if (ios != null)
                        ios.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            return ous.toByteArray();
        }
```

Log

```
eachImage : BufferedImage@3b7a74c6: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits =
24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@23c87f4d transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 960 height = 678 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
```

and it works fine "actually I don't know if the file holding my list or not" but when I try to deserialize I got NullPointerException because my list return null
case write:-

```
public MdapApplication DeserializeApp(SessionHandler Sbean , String Path) {
        setsHandler(Sbean);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(Path +"\\"+ "app.proj");            
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            MdapApplication DF = (MdapApplication) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
            return DF;
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Application class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

> then I get the objects from the file

```
 MdapApplication temp = obm.DeserializeApp(getsHandler(), amfFile.getPath());
    getDraftApp() = temp;
for (BufferedImage eachImage : getsHandler().getDraftApp().getSerializeImages() ) {
            System.out.println("eachImage : "+eachImage);
            ImageIO.write(eachImage, "png", new File(getsHandler().getDraftApp().getPath() +"\\"+ "myImage.png")); // png is lossless
        }
```

Log

```
25-Aug-2017 03:48:24.266 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-790]
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{apps.modify(mdapApp)}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{apps.modify(mdapApp)}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 35 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Beans.HomeScreenBean.deserializeImages(HomeScreenBean.java:271)
at Beans.HomeScreenBean.modify(HomeScreenBean.java:301)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more

25-Aug-2017 03:48:24.353 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-790]
com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Beans.HomeScreenBean.deserializeImages(HomeScreenBean.java:271)
at Beans.HomeScreenBean.modify(HomeScreenBean.java:301)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more
```

I search for two days and I found nothing BTW "My List could contains png-jpg"

Comment: What's throwing the NPE? Show us your stack trace.

Comment: in for (BufferedImage eachImage : getsHandler().getDraftApp().getSerializeImages() )...

Comment: the list NPE when deserialize

Comment: Stop throwing us crumbs in the comment section. Please [edit] your post to include any relevant information.

Comment: The NPE is at `Beans.HomeScreenBean.deserializeImages(HomeScreenBean.java` line 271. You haven't posted the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the file size is less than 1000 you don't create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, so `ous.toByteArray()` will throw an NPE.

Obviously.

Comment: I've no problem when serialize my problem when deserialize the list of BufferedImage return null I don't know why!

Comment: The code I am referring to is in `public byte[] read(...)`.Surely you can see that for yourself? This is deserialization code, not serialization code.

Comment: BTW I tried to serialize and deserialize "just for testing" in the same function it works without saving it in one file

Comment: I use byte[] read(..) to read "Serialize" the Images then add it to list like this getSerializeImages().add(ImageIO.read(new 
       ByteArrayInputStream(read(image))));

Comment: and it work when I print the content (eachImage : BufferedImage@3b7a74c6: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits ...)

Comment: then I write the Object (out.writeObject(getsHandler().getDraftApp());) that hold the List of BufferedImage and it success but the deserialize return the content of the file and list of BufferedImage return null